# How can I use multiple case statements inside a single alias in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, moodle

How can I attribute multiple CASE statements to a single ALIAS?

Assuming I have the following tables. Each 'id' column is a bigint, and all other fields are varchar(255). 'some_word' is a Product Name that has recently rebranded to another name, and I need to generate a report that all occurrences of 'some_word' for our content managers to use to replace the old name with the new name.

```
tbl_course c
------------------------------------------------------
| id  | fullname    | shortname | summary            |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | some_word   | AB        | apples and bananas |
| 788 | Jays Course | JC        | xyz some_word      |
------------------------------------------------------

tbl_assign a
--------------------------------------------
| id | name            | intro             |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | some_word No. 5 | Hello, some_word! |
| 9  | cats            | Not Dogs          |
--------------------------------------------

tbl_data_content dc
---------------------------------
| id | description | modulename |
---------------------------------
| 51 | my data     | some_word  | 
| 70 | some_word   | carrots    | 
---------------------------------
```

I am required to create a single SELECT statement that returns all values of 'some_word' across the entire database as follows:

```
--------------------------------------------
| id  | Entity Name     | Entity Type      |
--------------------------------------------
| 1   | some_word       | tbl_course       |
| 788 | Jays Course     | tbl_course       |
| 1   | some_word No. 5 | tbl_assign       |
| 51  | my data         | tbl_data_content | 
| 70  | some_word       | tbl_data_content |
--------------------------------------------
```

The alias 'Entity Name' should contain c.fullname, a.name, and dc.modulename (the 'name' of the module they need to edt).

The alias 'Entity Type' should contain the table name (tbl_course, tbl_assign, and tbl_data_content).

The alias 'Id' should contain c.id, a.id and dc.id.

I assume the best method is to use three ALIASES ('id', 'Entity Name' and 'Entity Type') that each contains multiple CASE statements that restrict the returning data to 'LIKE '%some_word%'. However, my attempts to attribute multiple CASE statements to a single ALIAS has failed.

How can I do this? I'll be running this across multiple instances of this application we need to change, and each of these instances is on either MySQL, MariaDB or PostgreSQL databases, so I'd like to create a report I can easily import and run in each instance.

Your help is greatly appreciated :)

I've tried nesting the CASE statements within each other. However, this is assuming whatever values in the first (top) CASE returns TRUE, which may not be the case. E.g.

```sql
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN c.fullname LIKE '%some_word%'
      THEN c.fullname 
      CASE WHEN c.shortname LIKE '%some_word%'
         THEN c.fullname
      END
   END AS 'Entity Name'
   --repeat for each table
FROM tbl_course c, tbl_assign a, tbl_data_content dc
```

Comment: I don't see the connection between the entity names and the three tables for which you provided sample data.  Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the 'Entity Name' column in the returned dataset should contain the name of the entity as they see it within the application (c.fullname, a.name, and dc.modulename) so the users that will use this report can match the records to the entities within the application (Moodle 3.6.5).

Comment: Entity Name is one of the aliases I want to use. - I've edited the original post to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single SELECT query (as in really just a single SELECT) is probably impossible here.

You could hard-code every table field that can contain `some_word` in a SELECT query and use UNION to combine everything in a single result set.

```
SELECT [id]
     , [fullname] as [Entity Name]
     , 'tbl_course' as [Entity Type]
  FROM [tbl_course]
 WHERE [fullname] LIKE '%some_word%'

 UNION

SELECT [id]
     , [fullname]
     , 'tbl_course'
  FROM [tbl_course]
 WHERE [shortname] LIKE '%some_word%'

 UNION

SELECT [id]
     , [name]
     , 'tbl_assign'
  FROM [tbl_assign]
 WHERE [name] LIKE '%some_word%'

 UNION

SELECT [id]
     , [name]
     , 'tbl_assign'
  FROM [tbl_assign]
 WHERE [intro] LIKE '%some_word%'

 UNION

SELECT [id]
     , [description] 'tbl_data_content'
  FROM [tbl_data_content]
 WHERE [description] LIKE '%some_word%'

 UNION

SELECT [id]
     , [description] 'tbl_data_content'
  FROM [tbl_data_content]
 WHERE [modulename] LIKE '%some_word%';
```

This query (which formally is a single SQL query) should yield the results in your question. I have not tested it, however.

You will have to add additional SELECT queries for other table/field combinations yourself.

If you do not want to hard-code it or if you need more flexibility, you could create a SQL script that dynamically creates/builds the query above. But in that case, you still need a table (or other data source) that contains a list of all the fields in every table that can contain `some_word`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh, this looks like what I want! I didn't know the UNION function existed. I'll try this out and let you know here.

Comment: OK. :) Yes, `UNION` can be useful. There is also a `UNION ALL`, which keeps duplicates. And if you only want records that match in both queries, there is also the `INTERSECT` operator: `SELECT * FROM A INTERSECT SELECT * FROM B` will show all records that are both in A and in B. Note that A and B need to have the same structure (same field count and field types). And you can perhaps also use `EXCEPT` if you need everything from A that is *not* in B. It's all more or less derived from mathematical set theory. The documentation of your DBMS will contain a lot more info about these.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `union all` and normalizing the data in a subquery.  I think you can concatenate the values for the search,

```
select id, entityname, entitytype,
from ((select id, fullname as entityname, 'tbl_course' as entitytype
              concat(fullname, '|', shortname, '|', summary) as tosearch
       from tbl_course
      ) union all
      (select id, name as entityname, 'tbl_course' as entittype
              concat(name, '|', intro) as tosearch
       from tbl_assign
      ) union all
      (select id, description as entityname, 'tbl_data_content' as entittype
              concat(description, '|', modulename) as tosearch
       from tbl_data_content
      )
     ) x
where tosearch like <pattern here>
```

Comment: With UNION ALL, possible duplicates will not be eliminated. for example when multiple fields in the same record contain `some_word`. Unless you specify which field it is, but perhaps that is unnecessarily too much detail for the OP (because it was not specified in his expected results). I considered using a table expression or CTE too, but I did not see any added value. Can you please explain why you advise to "normalize" the data in a more complex and (imho) unnecessary subquery?

Comment: Ah. I just see that you have to specify the search pattern only once. That's indeed very nice.

Answer (score 0):

> YOU CAN USE MULTIPLE CONDITIONS IN SINGLE CASE LIKE THIS

```
CASE WHEN [CONDITION] THEN [RESULT] 
     WHEN [CONDITION] THEN [RESULT] 
     WHEN ..... THEN [RESULT] 
     ELSE [DEFAULT] 
END
```